# Existence of a map of algebras over a ring which is not a map of algebras over another ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, power-series

I am trying to find a counterexample for a general statement that I thought to be true until not so long ago, but that now I suspect to be false. I believe that a very special case of the statement can be stated as follows.

> **Question:** Let $(t)$ be the ideal generated by $t$ in the $k$-algebra $k[[t]]$ of infinite power series over $t$. Then $(t)$ is also a module over the polynomial ring $k[t]$. Is every homomorphism of $(t)$ to itself as a $k[t]$-module also a homomorphism as a $k[[t]]$-module?

I believe it to be false because, as a $k[[t]]$-algebra, $(t)$ is free over $t$, while as a $k[t]$-module it cannot be generated by a single element. However, requiring that the morphisms respect the multiplicative structure is a pretty strong requirement...

I believe a possible counterexample to the statement might be given by defining $\phi(t^n)=t^n$ for any $n\ge0$, but $\phi(S(t))=0$ for some infinite power series (i.e. not a polynomial) $S(t)$. This is not trivial to construct, though. For example, we cannot set $\phi(S(t))=0$ for **all** infinite series $S(t)$, else
$$0=\phi\left(\sum_{n\ge1}t^n\right)=\phi(t)+\phi\left(\sum_{n\ge2}t^n\right)=\phi(t)=t\ ,$$
which is a contradiction.

I would prefer a constructive example of such a map $\phi$ (or a proof that the statement above is true, of course), but an existence example would also be fine.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the definition of $\overline{k[[t]]}$.  Is it the non-unital ring consisting of all power series with no constant term?

Comment: "Quotienting the 1 away" in a ring generally yields the zero ring.

Comment: Yes, but seen as a commutative algebra over $k[[x]]$ and $k[x]$.

Comment: @MattSamuel The quotient is taken as $k$-vector space.

Comment: When you take that quotient, what happens to the multiplicative structure? It sounds like you actually want to take a subalgebra, not a quotient.

Comment: @MattSamuel It's just the non-unital ring of power series without constant term.

Comment: Sigh! So your $\overline{k[[t]]}$ is just the ideal generated by $t$!.Why not just write $(t)$?

Comment: Here is what I think you asking (in standard terminology). *Let $(t)$ be the ideal generated by $t$ in the $k$-algebra $k[[t]]$ of infinite power series over $t$. Then $(t)$ is also a module over the polynomial ring $k[t]$. Is every homomorphism of $(t)$ to itself as a $k[t]$-module also a homomorphism as a $k[[t]]$-module?* Is that a correct statement of your question? (If so, the answer is yes.)

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, it is. And where can I find a proof? (I will accept an answer with a reference, if you desire.)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question to reflect your response to my comment.

Comment: @RobArthan Done, I copied and pasted the version of the statement you wrote.

Comment: As a $k[[t]]$-module, $(t)$ is isomorphic to $k[[t]]$, right?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard No, because it doesn't have the unit $1$.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud - Thanks for your answer. Sadly I don't understand it.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: Pierre wrote **as a $k[[t]]$-module$**. Modules aren't required to have multiplication or multiplicative units. $(t)$ is isomorphic to $k[[t]]$ as a $k[[t]]$- module.

Comment: If we knew that $\text{Hom}_{k[t]}(k[[t]]/k[t],k[[t]])\ne0$, this would clearly solve the problem.

Comment: What is a presentation of $k[[t]]$ as a $k[t]$-module? Is this known?

Comment: @MinseonShin: if $R$ is any ring and $M$ is any $R$-module you can cook up a presentation of $M$ with $M$ as the set of generators. I expect you are looking for something more interesting.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, I am looking for a presentation with "fewer" generators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: try the naive approach to proving that a $k[t]$-module homomorphism of $(t)$ to itself is also a $k[[t]]$-module homomorphism. When you evaluate a product $fg$ in $k[[t]]$, the $n$-th coefficient in the result is unchanged if you replace the formal power series $f = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ...$ by the polynomial $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n$